# Getting Startup Location In Windows

Tags: vb.net, directory, startup

I've written a small program to open at startup, but I want to give the user the ability to delete it from showing on startup by clicking a button.
But it needs to be compatible on XP, Vista and Windows 7. 
Is there a line of code which will get the default startup folder path automatically so I can then delete it using my button?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are wanting is the [SpecialFolder.Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx). and use the [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) methods

Something like this `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)`

To do your deletion you need to use [System.IO.File.Delete(path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)

To check to see what files are out there try making a console application and use this code.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup)

    For Each file In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path)
        Console.WriteLine(file)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: so "environment.startup" is all i need?

Comment: Right i have this, --- Dim startupfolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup)       how can i delete from this location now? i will know the exact filename

Comment: i know how to delete a file i just dont know how to get that "startupfolder" variable to be the path before the file name such as "startupfolder\testdelete.txt"

Comment: dim path as string = startupfolder & "\" & filename

Comment: Thankyou very much - one final thing (i think) its saying that my filename (testing.txt) isnt declared ----------------------------------------  Dim startupfolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)
        Dim path As String = startupfolder & "\" & testing.txt
        System.IO.File.Delete(path)

Comment: You probably won't have permission to delete from CommonStartup on Vista/7.

Comment: You need to enclose your file name in quotes i.e. "testing.txt"

Comment: ive turned off UAC and just tested - i can delete straight from the folder view

Comment: i tried the quotes as it seemed the logical way but to no avail

Comment: right added a bit of debugging to figure this out. i changed my code to this and got file not found ----  Dim startupfolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)
        Dim path As String = startupfolder & "\" & "testing.txt"


        If System.IO.File.Exists("testing.txt") = True Then

            System.IO.File.Delete("testing.txt")
            MsgBox("File Deleted")
        Else
            MsgBox("File Not Found")


        End If

Comment: Is your file located in the common startup directory or the user specific startup directory. Also make sure it is not a shortcut you are trying to delete. Try the first example that I gave.

Comment: not entirely sure how you mean. I can see it if i click start, all programs and click on the Startup folder, the "testing.txt" is in ther  (windows 7 by the way)

Comment: You have 2 startup locations. One is the global one, the other is user specific. You are using the global with the CommonStartup enumeration, the other is for user specific startup files. They both get mapped to the same folder on the start menu

Comment: even if i change the end of the environment string variable to commonstartup and not just startup it says file not found

Comment: is this a shortcut? if so use the .lnk file extension. I added some additional code in the answer. I beleive I have answered the first question, and we are starting to exceed the amount of comments that is preferred. I suggest that you place another question if you run into any more problems

Comment: its not a shortcut. ive modified my code out of curiosity and changed the ("testing.txt") on my if statement to the actual file path -- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup --- and it still doesnt work. ive even put a try catch in and no error messages at all

Comment: You may be running into a permissions issue though it should be throwing an error, did you try the additional code I put in the question?

Comment: yes i got this as an output --- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\desktop.ini
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\testing.txt

Comment: i cant believe ive been staring at the problem for about 20 mins - i changed the path to ("testing.txt") for some reason - probably because its 12am now here lol - when its meant to be path - and i also had the textfile named as testing.txt.txt ---- sorry for wasting your time with such a stupid mistake lol - thankyou so much though @mark

Comment: Any reason why trying to call Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup might give me an error with my .NET 2.0 build configuration but not .NET 4.0? The error says CommonStartup does not exist on Environment.SpecialFolder, but it looks like it was added in Windows NT